# Autohotkey in proxy environment

Tags: proxy, autohotkey

I have made a script for myself that requires internet connection to work fine. It has many "UrlDownloadToFile" command in it.
My problem is, I am working in a proxy environment, where we need to add up proxy in our browser and then username and password, to work over the internet.

Because of this, my Application isn't working fine at all.
Please help.

Comment: AHK will by default use the proxy used by Internet Explorer, just configure the proxy there. If you can't do that, you'll need to use some kind of API, e.g. [WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382925(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Yes i have configured proxy in Internet Explorer. But where to add username and password for the proxy. Autohotkey doesn't prompt for it.

Comment: Oh, I read over the password part. In this case, you won't get out of using something else than `UrlDownloadToFile`, because to my knowledge, it doesn't support the use of proxy credentials. There's a good AHK library called [httpQuery](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/30624-function-httpquery-get-and-post-requests-update-036/). Have a look into it. If you desperately want to use `UrlDownloadToFile`, you'll need some kind of local proxy that forwards your requests to the real proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complicated download situations I use the command line tool [Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) which works great with AHK and not only does proxies, but also postdata, cookies and user agents.

A proxy example call that downloads the google homepage into the file result.txt using a proxy looks like this

```
URL := "http://www.google.com"
Runcurl = curl.exe "%URL%" -x user:password@proxyhost:port -o "result.txt" 
Runwait, %comspec% /c %RunCurl%, , Hide
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is somewhat of a controlled bypass. If you trust the site (which i'd assume you do since you have a username and password) go into Internet Explorer settings and add the site to the "Trusted Sites" section of the "Security" tab.

(Open IE, Menu, Internet Options, Security, Trusted Sites, Sites, -Optional- uncheck bottom checkbox regarding https, click ADD)

Now login to the site with IE and attempt the download with this script (NOTE: Proxy Server is oct.oct.oct.oct:Port)

```
Blah := URLDownload("http://google.com")
FileAppend, %Blah%, Blah.csv

    UrlDownload(URL, ProxyServer = "")
    {
        ver := ""
        Try
        {
            WebRequest := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
            If ProxyServer
                WebRequest.SetProxy(2,ProxyServer)
            WebRequest.Open("GET", URL)
            WebRequest.Send()
            ver := WebRequest.ResponseText
        }
        WebRequest := ""
        return ver
    }
```